# redirecting an .htaccess with regular expression

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are SO many .htaccess redirect posts on here, but unfortunately none that match my situation that I can find, and I'm struggling with understanding regular expressions to make this work.  My situation:

Rebuilt a real estate site on Wordpress.  The site had been established for many years before, and therefor had a ton of Google-crawled property URLs.  The new site uses a completely different permalink structure with brand new properties and google search console is coming up with tons of 404 errors.

Old structure: domain.com/2008/10/10/post-title/
New structure: domain.com/properties/post-title/

I'd like to be able to write a .htaccess redirect to point ALL URLs that start with /0000/00/00/whatever to the home page.  I've done some research onregular expressions and I've found similar cases but none that I can make work for me.  They seem to just be ignored.

Guide site that I used: https://24ways.org/2013/url-rewriting-for-the-fearful/

My relevant .htaccess code:

```
# BEGIN custom rewrite rules
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/.*/$ http://hardestyrealestate.com/ [R=301]
# END custom rewrite rules

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Basically my custom redirect is a result of hacking together multiple tutorials on regular expression to try to match the relevant "old" urls.  Can someone help me figure this one out?  Is my custom redirect in the wrong place? (does it need to be AFTER the wordpress redirect code)?  Help would be appreciated!

Dan

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of all the context of your system, but I'm wondering since you put ^ at the beginning of the match if perhaps it is adding http:// or https:// at the beginning and thus not matching? This is kind of a guess.

The other possibility that comes to mind is that / has a special meaning to your regex processor and you need to use / instead.

Comment: Appreciate your reply!  From what I read here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html it says that the ^ character matches the beginning of the string, and every tutorial that I've found has that character in there.  As to your second comment, both of your forward slashes look the same?  are they different in ways other than visual?

Another note: I put my rule into a tester here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it worked like it should according to them!? what the heck?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Did you ever figure out what went wrong?

Comment: Nope, no dice.  I do appreciate your followup though!  Everything I read (and my test at htaccess.madewithlove.be) suggests that it's right, so I'm out of ideas.